# Citrix-Session starts but hangs for about 3 Minutes

Tags: citrix

I logon to our citrix through web-access (native-client 12.0.0.6410 from my Win7 64-bit notebook). There is one published application: the Desktop.
I can hear the start-up-sound and see the desktop, even the applications if the session was disconnected. But one mouse-click and the the Citrix-Oneline Plug-in Window becomes "not responding" and greyed out for about 3 Minutes.

After this delay everythings works fine or the window has gone away and i have to restart the login-process again...

I disabled the local drives, printers, usb-devices, micro and camera but nothing helped.
What might be the reason and where to search?

**Update:** I believe in a problem of citrix-client or IE when asking how to access the lokal drives (none, read-only or read-write). With FireFox it connects somehow better...

Comment: Does this happen with everyone or just you?

Comment: It's just for me and only if i login connected my notebook at the local lan. Even a reconnect to an existing Session from my homeoffice runs like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had This problem happening to me from a VPN connection and in LAN it was working fine,
The issue was solved by deleting the many printers i had (some were orphaned printers, they weren't available on a Novell print server anymore)
i later found out Citrix fixed this issue in a newer version (i'm using XenApp Plugin for hosted application v11)
I think this is the page that explains this issue:
http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX122425